# Computing Integrals over space of Hermitian Matrices.

Tags: integration, matrices

I am currently working on an example for my research, and I'm getting stuck. Without going over the details of what things mean explicitly, I would like some help computing this integral. I will define all necessary notations below.

$\int_{\mathscr{H}_N} tr(H^4) (2\pi)^{\frac{N^2}{2}} (2)^{\frac{N^2 - N}{2}} exp^{-\frac{1}{2} tr(H^2)} \prod_{i=1}^N dx_{ii} \prod_{i<j} dx_{ij}dy_{ij}$

It's rather messy, but $\mathscr{H}_N$ is space of $N$ x $N$ hermitian matrices. Here are some of the following things necessary for this.

$tr(H^4) = \sum h_{a, b} h_{b, c} h_{c,d} h_{d, a}$, where the sum is taken over all combinations of the $h$'s. So it's 3 terms total, just permuting the order.

$dx_{ii} = h_{ii}$, which are the elements along the diagonal of the hermitician matrix,

$dx_{ij} = Re( h_{ij})$, $dy_{ij} = Im(h_{ij})$. If my memory servers correctly, I bleieve the integral is supposed to be $2N^3 + N$.

I know this is very complicated and lacking some deeper notational things, but hopefully someone here will have seen this before.

Comment: See Subsection 1.6.1 of [this book](http://f3.tiera.ru/2/P_Physics/PT_Thermodynamics,%20statistical%20physics/Forrester%20P.%20Log-gases%20and%20random%20matrices%20%28PUP,%202010%29%28ISBN%200691128294%29%28O%29%28806s%29_PT_.pdf).

Comment: This helps some, but I need to work this out explicitly, and that's what I'm having trouble with.